How to select single vertex rather than an area of vertices?

I am following a tutorial from Blender Bros. I can't figure out how to stop Blender from selecting an area of vertices instead of a single vertex. Proportional edit mode is off, and I have not applied subdivision to the object.

Pleae share your Blend file so that we can see what's going on.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. It would also be helpful if you could paste a link to the tutorial you are following. Also why do you have two bevel modifiers on your object?

Which vertex did you try to select?

2nd bevel is there for bottom edge needed to smooth out it. . I am following Blender bros here is the link "https://www.blenderbros.com/products/hard-surface-modeling-jumpstart/categories/2150162633/posts/2157168359"

AFAIK, the Select gizmo tool will always drag to a bounding area of some sort. With default settings, I believe simply clicking a vertex will select it. I use the older control setting where right-click is select, which is chosen when starting Blender for the first time. This works no matter what gizmo tool is active.

Sorry for the late reply ! I will try and do that.
